# Close votes on 5-year-old questions with 20K+ upvotes

Tags: discussion, review-queues, specific-question, vote-to-close

In the Close Queue [this 5-year old question with > 20,000 upvotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array) came up.

If someone flags a question that is protected, and has so many upvotes, maybe the system could reject it, or pass it to an administrator.

For this case, everyone who reviews it is saying Leave Open.

Comment: Well this is a laugh.  The close reason is "primarily opinion based."  I needed a pick-me-up this morning.

Comment: Seems like the system is working :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The fact that a question has a lot of upvotes doesn't automatically mean it doesn't merit closure.  Lots of close-worthy posts have gotten a lot of upvotes.

This particular highly upvoted question doesn't merit closure, and the review queue correctly indicated that.  Had it actually merited closure, we would *want* reviewers to look at it, and close it accordingly.